# Abstracción en JavaScript, algún ejemplo en código?

Tags: javascript, herencia

Entiendo el concepto como tal, que si no me equivoco, se trata justamente de abstraer los datos mas relevantes de un objeto, los datos que lo diferencian de los demás, pero al buscar información solo encuentro teórico y nada de código, por ende no se bien como se aplica en código JavaScript, no se si esto se aplica dentro de un `class` o como.

Por ejemplo el siguiente ejemplo (demasiado sencillo, lo sé) sería abstracción?

```
class SerVivo {

  constructor(edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
  }

  alimentarse() {}
  
}
```

Y luego debo de utilizar la herencia para darle contexto? Como:

```
  class Perro extends SerVivo {
  
  constructor(edad,raza) {
    super(edad);
    this.raza = raza;
  }

  alimentarse() {
    console.log("Le gusta comer carne")
  }
```

}

De ser así, se podría decir que la abstracción y la herencia van de la mano?

Answer (score 1):

*De ser así, se podría decir que la abstracción y la herencia van de la mano?*

Me parece que no tienes muy claro el concepto de [abstracción](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstracci%C3%B3n_(inform%C3%A1tica)). Lo que has puesto en tu pregunta es un claro ejemplo de herencia, nada más. Un ejemplo básico de abstracción sería:

```
class SerVivo {

  constructor(edad, feeder) {
    this.edad = edad;
    this.feeder = feeder;
  }

  alimentarse() {
    feeder.feed(this.edad);
    /* Qué hace el feeder? Y yo que sé. Ni lo sé ni me importa.
     Me importa que lo hace, no el CÓMO lo hace.
     Yo solo sé que le paso la edad a ese método y el ser vivo se alimenta correctamente!
     Esto es abstracción. Sabemos que esto hace lo que necesitamos, pero el funcionamiento interno
     nos es completamente irrelevante. Es decir, abstraemos al programador del funcionamiento
     interno del método para que pueda centrarse en arreglar/hacer lo que necesite e ignorar lo demás*/
  }
}
```

Básicamente, la abstracción en programación consiste en "ocultar" (abstraer) la lógica de algo que no es necesario mostrar, como por ejemplo algunos cálculos complejos o accesos a la base de datos, de la vista del programador. Esto se consigue mediante el uso de interfaces o clases helper donde podemos encapsular ese pedazo de lógica.

---

También se suele conocer a este concepto como *caja negra*, puesto que sabemos que por un lado metemos X variables en una función, y a la salida obtenemos lo que necesitamos, pero no vemos el funcionamiento interno (de ahí lo de caja negra).